# Drawing a text in canvas HTML stops my algorithm

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an algorithm used to draw in Canvas HTML an itinerary given by points. Evrything works fine without adding the names on my points.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="mycanvas" width="100" height="100" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 50px;"></canvas>
  <script type='text/javascript'> 
window.onload=function(){
   
 var jsonServicesTT = [{"NAME":"Elephant","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Sunshine","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Flower","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Abricot","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Cake","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Mouse","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Uther","DIRECTION":"3"},{"NAME":"Arriba","DIRECTION":"3"},{"NAME":"Hola","DIRECTION":"3"},{"NAME":"Elephant","DIRECTION":"3"}];
 

 widthCan = 792;
 heightCan = 423;
 width = widthCan - 150;
 height = heightCan - 130;
 var perimetre = (width * 2 + height * 2);
 var colors = [];
 var colorTemp = '';
 var table = [];
 var direction = [];
 var resteFaire = [];
 var doubleColor = '';
 var nbSegment = 0;
 var percent = 0;
 var up =0;
 var right = 1;
 var left = 0;
 var bot = 0;
 var tailleSegment = 0;
 var decalX = 75;
 var decalY = 60;
 var NAME = '';
 
 
 var cRot='';
 var cRot2 = '';
 cRot = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
 ctxRot = cRot.getContext('2d');
 ctxRot.canvas.width = widthCan;
 ctxRot.canvas.height = heightCan;
 
 function findColors(direction){
  switch(direction)
  {
   case '1': 
    colors.push('red');
    colorTemp = 'red';
    break;
   case '2': 
    colors.push('blue');
    colorTemp = 'blue';
    break;
   case '3': 
    colors.push('DeepSkyBlue');
    colorTemp = 'DeepSkyBlue';
    break;
   case '4': 
    colors.push('Green');
    colorTemp = 'Green';
    break;
   default:  
    colors.push('Darkorange');  
    colorTemp = 'Darkorange';
  } 
 }
 /************** Rounded Rect *************/
 function roundRect(x, y, w, h, radius) {
  var r = x + w;
  var b = y + h;
  ctxRot.beginPath();
  ctxRot.strokeStyle = "#BDBDBD";
  ctxRot.lineWidth = "2";
  ctxRot.moveTo(x + radius, y);
  ctxRot.lineTo(r - radius, y);
  ctxRot.quadraticCurveTo(r, y, r, y + radius);
  ctxRot.lineTo(r, y + h - radius);
  ctxRot.quadraticCurveTo(r, b, r - radius, b);
  ctxRot.lineTo(x + radius, b);
  ctxRot.quadraticCurveTo(x, b, x, b - radius);
  ctxRot.lineTo(x, y + radius);
  ctxRot.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
  ctxRot.stroke();
 }
 
 function drawCircle(centerXFrom, centerYFrom, color){
  var radius = 5;
  ctxRot.beginPath();
  ctxRot.arc(centerXFrom + decalX, centerYFrom + decalY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctxRot.fillStyle = color;
  ctxRot.fill();
  ctxRot.lineWidth = 1;
  ctxRot.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  ctxRot.stroke();
  ctxRot.beginPath();
  /*if(bot == 1){
   ctxRot.translate(centerXFrom, centerYFrom);
   ctxRot.rotate(-Math.PI / 4);
   ctxRot.fillText(NAME, name.length - 50 , name.length);
   ctxRot.restore();
  }*/
 
 }
  
 function getSide(leg, taille) {
  findColors(leg["DIRECTION"]);
  NAME = leg["NAME"];
  if(right == 1 && taille < (height - yPrec)) { //si on peut placer le point sur le même côté que précédemment
   yPrec += taille;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
  }
  else if (right == 1 && taille > (height - yPrec)) { 
   var reste = height - yPrec; //calcul de combien de right il y a
   if(reste > width){ //si on passe de right à left sans passer par bot
    var resteY = reste - width;
    yPrec = height - resteY;
    xPrec = 0;
    right = 0;
    bot = 0;
    up =0;
    left = 1;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
    
   }
   else //si on passe de right à bot
   {
    var resteX = taille - reste; // calcul de combien il reste de distance après avoir déduit le right
    xPrec = width - resteX; // positionnement du point en Bot x
    yPrec = height;
    //writeBot(leg["NAME"], xPrec, yPrec); 
    right = 0;
    bot = 1;
    up =0;
    left = 0; 
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);        
   }
    
  }
  else if (bot == 1 && taille < xPrec){ //si on peut placer le point sur le même côté que précédemment
   xPrec = xPrec - taille;
   yPrec = height;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
    
  }
  else if(bot == 1 && taille > xPrec){ // si le nouveau point ne peut pas être sur le bot
   var resteY = taille - xPrec;
   if(resteY > height){ //si on passe de bot à up
    xPrec = resteY - height;
    yPrec = 0;
    right = 0;
    bot = 0;
    up =1;
    left = 0;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);    
     
   }
   else{ //si on passe de bot à left
    yPrec = height - resteY;
    xPrec = 0;
    bot = 0;
    left = 1;
    right = 0;
    up =0;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
   }
   
  }
  else if (left == 1 && taille < yPrec){
   yPrec = yPrec - taille;
   xPrec = 0;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
  }
  else if (left == 1 && taille > yPrec){
   var resteX = taille - yPrec;
   if (resteX > width){ //si on passe de left à right
    yPrec = resteX - width;
    xPrec = 0;
    up = 0;
    bot = 0;
    left = 0;
    right = 1;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
   }
   else{ //si on passe de left à bot
    xPrec = resteX;
    yPrec = 0;
    up = 1;
    bot = 0;
    left = 0;
    right = 0;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
   }
   
  }
  else if(up == 1 && taille < (width - xPrec) ){
   xPrec += taille;
   yPrec = 0;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
  }
  else if(up == 1 && taille > (width - xPrec)){
   var resteX = width - xPrec;
   xPrec = width;
   yPrec = taille - resteX;
   up = 0;
   bot = 0;
   left = 0;
   right = 1;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
  }
 
  
 }
 
 function drawCircleFirst(X, Y) {
  if(jsonServicesTT[0]["NAME"] == jsonServicesTT[(jsonServicesTT.length) - 1]["NAME"])
  {
   table.push(jsonServicesTT[0]);
   table.push(jsonServicesTT[(jsonServicesTT.length) - 1]);
   for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
    findColors(table[i]["DIRECTION"]);
   }
   doubleColor = true;
  }
  
  else
  {
   findColors(table[0]["DIRECTION"]);
   doubleColor = false;
  }  
  
  var radius = 6;
  var currentAngle = -0.5 * Math.PI;
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   var sliceAngle = 0.5 * 2 * Math.PI;
   ctxRot.beginPath();
   ctxRot.arc(X + decalX, Y + decalY, radius,currentAngle, currentAngle + sliceAngle);
   ctxRot.strokeStyle = '#003300';
   ctxRot.stroke();
   currentAngle += sliceAngle;
   ctxRot.lineTo(X + decalX, X + decalX);
   ctxRot.fillStyle = colors[i];
   
   ctxRot.fill();
  }
 }
 
 function getProportion(){
  if(doubleColor){
   nbSegment = jsonServicesTT.slice(1).length;
  }
  else nbSegment = jsonServicesTT.length;
  percent = 100/nbSegment;
  tailleSegment = (perimetre*percent)/100;
  
  for (var i = 1; i < nbSegment; i++){//premier et dernier points déjà placés
   getSide(jsonServicesTT[i], tailleSegment);
  }  
 }
  
 roundRect(decalX, decalY, width, height, 20);
 var firstPointX = width ;
 var firstPointY = (height/2);
 yPrec = firstPointY;
 xPrec = firstPointX;
 drawCircleFirst(firstPointX, firstPointY);
 getProportion();
}

  </script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

But when you uncomment the part used to insert text (please don't take care of the name's position as I'm just trying to make it work at first) in the drawCircle function, you can see that my points are no longer drawn.
I'm guessing it's a context issue as my name takes the color of the point but I don't know how to resolve that.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="mycanvas" width="100" height="100" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 50px;"></canvas>
  <script type='text/javascript'> 
window.onload=function(){
   
 var jsonServicesTT = [{"NAME":"Elephant","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Sunshine","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Flower","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Abricot","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Cake","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Mouse","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Uther","DIRECTION":"3"},{"NAME":"Arriba","DIRECTION":"3"},{"NAME":"Hola","DIRECTION":"3"},{"NAME":"Elephant","DIRECTION":"3"}];
 

 widthCan = 792;
 heightCan = 423;
 width = widthCan - 150;
 height = heightCan - 130;
 var perimetre = (width * 2 + height * 2);
 var colors = [];
 var colorTemp = '';
 var table = [];
 var direction = [];
 var resteFaire = [];
 var doubleColor = '';
 var nbSegment = 0;
 var percent = 0;
 var up =0;
 var right = 1;
 var left = 0;
 var bot = 0;
 var tailleSegment = 0;
 var decalX = 75;
 var decalY = 60;
 var NAME = '';
 
 
 var cRot='';
 var cRot2 = '';
 cRot = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
 ctxRot = cRot.getContext('2d');
 ctxRot.canvas.width = widthCan;
 ctxRot.canvas.height = heightCan;
 
 function findColors(direction){
  switch(direction)
  {
   case '1': 
    colors.push('red');
    colorTemp = 'red';
    break;
   case '2': 
    colors.push('blue');
    colorTemp = 'blue';
    break;
   case '3': 
    colors.push('DeepSkyBlue');
    colorTemp = 'DeepSkyBlue';
    break;
   case '4': 
    colors.push('Green');
    colorTemp = 'Green';
    break;
   default:  
    colors.push('Darkorange');  
    colorTemp = 'Darkorange';
  } 
 }
 /************** Rounded Rect *************/
 function roundRect(x, y, w, h, radius) {
  var r = x + w;
  var b = y + h;
  ctxRot.beginPath();
  ctxRot.strokeStyle = "#BDBDBD";
  ctxRot.lineWidth = "2";
  ctxRot.moveTo(x + radius, y);
  ctxRot.lineTo(r - radius, y);
  ctxRot.quadraticCurveTo(r, y, r, y + radius);
  ctxRot.lineTo(r, y + h - radius);
  ctxRot.quadraticCurveTo(r, b, r - radius, b);
  ctxRot.lineTo(x + radius, b);
  ctxRot.quadraticCurveTo(x, b, x, b - radius);
  ctxRot.lineTo(x, y + radius);
  ctxRot.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
  ctxRot.stroke();
 }
 
 function drawCircle(centerXFrom, centerYFrom, color){
  var radius = 5;
  ctxRot.beginPath();
  ctxRot.arc(centerXFrom + decalX, centerYFrom + decalY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctxRot.fillStyle = color;
  ctxRot.fill();
  ctxRot.lineWidth = 1;
  ctxRot.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  ctxRot.stroke();
  ctxRot.beginPath();
  if(bot == 1){
   ctxRot.translate(centerXFrom, centerYFrom);
   ctxRot.rotate(-Math.PI / 4);
   ctxRot.fillText(NAME, name.length - 50 , name.length);
   ctxRot.restore();
  }
 
 }
  
 function getSide(leg, taille) {
  findColors(leg["DIRECTION"]);
  NAME = leg["NAME"];
  if(right == 1 && taille < (height - yPrec)) { //si on peut placer le point sur le même côté que précédemment
   yPrec += taille;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
  }
  else if (right == 1 && taille > (height - yPrec)) { 
   var reste = height - yPrec; //calcul de combien de right il y a
   if(reste > width){ //si on passe de right à left sans passer par bot
    var resteY = reste - width;
    yPrec = height - resteY;
    xPrec = 0;
    right = 0;
    bot = 0;
    up =0;
    left = 1;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
    
   }
   else //si on passe de right à bot
   {
    var resteX = taille - reste; // calcul de combien il reste de distance après avoir déduit le right
    xPrec = width - resteX; // positionnement du point en Bot x
    yPrec = height;
    //writeBot(leg["NAME"], xPrec, yPrec); 
    right = 0;
    bot = 1;
    up =0;
    left = 0; 
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);        
   }
    
  }
  else if (bot == 1 && taille < xPrec){ //si on peut placer le point sur le même côté que précédemment
   xPrec = xPrec - taille;
   yPrec = height;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
    
  }
  else if(bot == 1 && taille > xPrec){ // si le nouveau point ne peut pas être sur le bot
   var resteY = taille - xPrec;
   if(resteY > height){ //si on passe de bot à up
    xPrec = resteY - height;
    yPrec = 0;
    right = 0;
    bot = 0;
    up =1;
    left = 0;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);    
     
   }
   else{ //si on passe de bot à left
    yPrec = height - resteY;
    xPrec = 0;
    bot = 0;
    left = 1;
    right = 0;
    up =0;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
   }
   
  }
  else if (left == 1 && taille < yPrec){
   yPrec = yPrec - taille;
   xPrec = 0;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
  }
  else if (left == 1 && taille > yPrec){
   var resteX = taille - yPrec;
   if (resteX > width){ //si on passe de left à right
    yPrec = resteX - width;
    xPrec = 0;
    up = 0;
    bot = 0;
    left = 0;
    right = 1;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
   }
   else{ //si on passe de left à bot
    xPrec = resteX;
    yPrec = 0;
    up = 1;
    bot = 0;
    left = 0;
    right = 0;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
   }
   
  }
  else if(up == 1 && taille < (width - xPrec) ){
   xPrec += taille;
   yPrec = 0;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
  }
  else if(up == 1 && taille > (width - xPrec)){
   var resteX = width - xPrec;
   xPrec = width;
   yPrec = taille - resteX;
   up = 0;
   bot = 0;
   left = 0;
   right = 1;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
  }
 
  
 }
 
 function drawCircleFirst(X, Y) {
  if(jsonServicesTT[0]["NAME"] == jsonServicesTT[(jsonServicesTT.length) - 1]["NAME"])
  {
   table.push(jsonServicesTT[0]);
   table.push(jsonServicesTT[(jsonServicesTT.length) - 1]);
   for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
    findColors(table[i]["DIRECTION"]);
   }
   doubleColor = true;
  }
  
  else
  {
   findColors(table[0]["DIRECTION"]);
   doubleColor = false;
  }  
  
  var radius = 6;
  var currentAngle = -0.5 * Math.PI;
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   var sliceAngle = 0.5 * 2 * Math.PI;
   ctxRot.beginPath();
   ctxRot.arc(X + decalX, Y + decalY, radius,currentAngle, currentAngle + sliceAngle);
   ctxRot.strokeStyle = '#003300';
   ctxRot.stroke();
   currentAngle += sliceAngle;
   ctxRot.lineTo(X + decalX, X + decalX);
   ctxRot.fillStyle = colors[i];
   
   ctxRot.fill();
  }
 }
 
 function getProportion(){
  if(doubleColor){
   nbSegment = jsonServicesTT.slice(1).length;
  }
  else nbSegment = jsonServicesTT.length;
  percent = 100/nbSegment;
  tailleSegment = (perimetre*percent)/100;
  
  for (var i = 1; i < nbSegment; i++){//premier et dernier points déjà placés
   getSide(jsonServicesTT[i], tailleSegment);
  }  
 }
  
 roundRect(decalX, decalY, width, height, 20);
 var firstPointX = width ;
 var firstPointY = (height/2);
 yPrec = firstPointY;
 xPrec = firstPointX;
 drawCircleFirst(firstPointX, firstPointY);
 getProportion();
}

  </script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctx.restore` restores a *previously saved state* to the ctx on which it was called. I see that in your problem code, you have a call to this function (on the ctxRot object) The problem is, you're trying to restore a state that you don't appear to be saving beforehand.

Adding in a call to `ctxRot.save()` appears to do the trick - text is rendered to the bottom 3 circles and, all 9 circles are shown.
This is how I'd be changing it to deal with this particular problem. I've not looked closely enough to know if I should expect to see more text or not.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="mycanvas" width="100" height="100" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 50px;"></canvas>
  <script type='text/javascript'> 
window.onload=function(){
   
 var jsonServicesTT = [{"NAME":"Elephant","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Sunshine","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Flower","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Abricot","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Cake","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Mouse","DIRECTION":"4"},{"NAME":"Uther","DIRECTION":"3"},{"NAME":"Arriba","DIRECTION":"3"},{"NAME":"Hola","DIRECTION":"3"},{"NAME":"Elephant","DIRECTION":"3"}];
 

 widthCan = 792;
 heightCan = 423;
 width = widthCan - 150;
 height = heightCan - 130;
 var perimetre = (width * 2 + height * 2);
 var colors = [];
 var colorTemp = '';
 var table = [];
 var direction = [];
 var resteFaire = [];
 var doubleColor = '';
 var nbSegment = 0;
 var percent = 0;
 var up =0;
 var right = 1;
 var left = 0;
 var bot = 0;
 var tailleSegment = 0;
 var decalX = 75;
 var decalY = 60;
 var NAME = '';
 
 
 var cRot='';
 var cRot2 = '';
 cRot = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
 ctxRot = cRot.getContext('2d');
 ctxRot.canvas.width = widthCan;
 ctxRot.canvas.height = heightCan;
 
 function findColors(direction){
  switch(direction)
  {
   case '1': 
    colors.push('red');
    colorTemp = 'red';
    break;
   case '2': 
    colors.push('blue');
    colorTemp = 'blue';
    break;
   case '3': 
    colors.push('DeepSkyBlue');
    colorTemp = 'DeepSkyBlue';
    break;
   case '4': 
    colors.push('Green');
    colorTemp = 'Green';
    break;
   default:  
    colors.push('Darkorange');  
    colorTemp = 'Darkorange';
  } 
 }
 /************** Rounded Rect *************/
 function roundRect(x, y, w, h, radius) {
  var r = x + w;
  var b = y + h;
  ctxRot.beginPath();
  ctxRot.strokeStyle = "#BDBDBD";
  ctxRot.lineWidth = "2";
  ctxRot.moveTo(x + radius, y);
  ctxRot.lineTo(r - radius, y);
  ctxRot.quadraticCurveTo(r, y, r, y + radius);
  ctxRot.lineTo(r, y + h - radius);
  ctxRot.quadraticCurveTo(r, b, r - radius, b);
  ctxRot.lineTo(x + radius, b);
  ctxRot.quadraticCurveTo(x, b, x, b - radius);
  ctxRot.lineTo(x, y + radius);
  ctxRot.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
  ctxRot.stroke();
 }
 
 function drawCircle(centerXFrom, centerYFrom, color){
  var radius = 5;
  ctxRot.beginPath();
  ctxRot.arc(centerXFrom + decalX, centerYFrom + decalY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctxRot.fillStyle = color;
  ctxRot.fill();
  ctxRot.lineWidth = 1;
  ctxRot.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  ctxRot.stroke();
  ctxRot.beginPath();
  if(bot == 1){
   ctxRot.save();   // *** Added this line *** //
   ctxRot.translate(centerXFrom, centerYFrom);
   ctxRot.rotate(-Math.PI / 4);
   ctxRot.fillText(NAME, name.length - 50 , name.length);
   ctxRot.restore();
  }
 
 }
  
 function getSide(leg, taille) {
  findColors(leg["DIRECTION"]);
  NAME = leg["NAME"];
  if(right == 1 && taille < (height - yPrec)) { //si on peut placer le point sur le même côté que précédemment
   yPrec += taille;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
  }
  else if (right == 1 && taille > (height - yPrec)) { 
   var reste = height - yPrec; //calcul de combien de right il y a
   if(reste > width){ //si on passe de right à left sans passer par bot
    var resteY = reste - width;
    yPrec = height - resteY;
    xPrec = 0;
    right = 0;
    bot = 0;
    up =0;
    left = 1;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
    
   }
   else //si on passe de right à bot
   {
    var resteX = taille - reste; // calcul de combien il reste de distance après avoir déduit le right
    xPrec = width - resteX; // positionnement du point en Bot x
    yPrec = height;
    //writeBot(leg["NAME"], xPrec, yPrec); 
    right = 0;
    bot = 1;
    up =0;
    left = 0; 
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);        
   }
    
  }
  else if (bot == 1 && taille < xPrec){ //si on peut placer le point sur le même côté que précédemment
   xPrec = xPrec - taille;
   yPrec = height;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
    
  }
  else if(bot == 1 && taille > xPrec){ // si le nouveau point ne peut pas être sur le bot
   var resteY = taille - xPrec;
   if(resteY > height){ //si on passe de bot à up
    xPrec = resteY - height;
    yPrec = 0;
    right = 0;
    bot = 0;
    up =1;
    left = 0;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);    
     
   }
   else{ //si on passe de bot à left
    yPrec = height - resteY;
    xPrec = 0;
    bot = 0;
    left = 1;
    right = 0;
    up =0;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
   }
   
  }
  else if (left == 1 && taille < yPrec){
   yPrec = yPrec - taille;
   xPrec = 0;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
  }
  else if (left == 1 && taille > yPrec){
   var resteX = taille - yPrec;
   if (resteX > width){ //si on passe de left à right
    yPrec = resteX - width;
    xPrec = 0;
    up = 0;
    bot = 0;
    left = 0;
    right = 1;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
   }
   else{ //si on passe de left à bot
    xPrec = resteX;
    yPrec = 0;
    up = 1;
    bot = 0;
    left = 0;
    right = 0;
    drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
   }
   
  }
  else if(up == 1 && taille < (width - xPrec) ){
   xPrec += taille;
   yPrec = 0;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
  }
  else if(up == 1 && taille > (width - xPrec)){
   var resteX = width - xPrec;
   xPrec = width;
   yPrec = taille - resteX;
   up = 0;
   bot = 0;
   left = 0;
   right = 1;
   drawCircle(xPrec, yPrec, colorTemp, NAME);
  }
 
  
 }
 
 function drawCircleFirst(X, Y) {
  if(jsonServicesTT[0]["NAME"] == jsonServicesTT[(jsonServicesTT.length) - 1]["NAME"])
  {
   table.push(jsonServicesTT[0]);
   table.push(jsonServicesTT[(jsonServicesTT.length) - 1]);
   for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
    findColors(table[i]["DIRECTION"]);
   }
   doubleColor = true;
  }
  
  else
  {
   findColors(table[0]["DIRECTION"]);
   doubleColor = false;
  }  
  
  var radius = 6;
  var currentAngle = -0.5 * Math.PI;
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   var sliceAngle = 0.5 * 2 * Math.PI;
   ctxRot.beginPath();
   ctxRot.arc(X + decalX, Y + decalY, radius,currentAngle, currentAngle + sliceAngle);
   ctxRot.strokeStyle = '#003300';
   ctxRot.stroke();
   currentAngle += sliceAngle;
   ctxRot.lineTo(X + decalX, X + decalX);
   ctxRot.fillStyle = colors[i];
   
   ctxRot.fill();
  }
 }
 
 function getProportion(){
  if(doubleColor){
   nbSegment = jsonServicesTT.slice(1).length;
  }
  else nbSegment = jsonServicesTT.length;
  percent = 100/nbSegment;
  tailleSegment = (perimetre*percent)/100;
  
  for (var i = 1; i < nbSegment; i++){//premier et dernier points déjà placés
   getSide(jsonServicesTT[i], tailleSegment);
  }  
 }
  
 roundRect(decalX, decalY, width, height, 20);
 var firstPointX = width ;
 var firstPointY = (height/2);
 yPrec = firstPointY;
 xPrec = firstPointX;
 drawCircleFirst(firstPointX, firstPointY);
 getProportion();
}

  </script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, it's nice to know what's wrong, all the text is correctly displayed.

Comment: You're welcome. Learning how to fish is more important than being given a hot meal right now. Both together is even better again! :)